# Where in code can I check if my uicollectionviewcontroller is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView in my app which display selected items by the user. After click on the specified UICollectionViewCell I display UIAlertView where user can set some values. After click on OK button of UIAlertView selected items in UICollectionView is deleting by using deleteItemAtIndexPaths: method. All I wanna do is after deleting all UICollectionViewCells, set visibility of UICollectionView by using method setHidden: , but I don't know where to put my if statement to check if my collectionview is empty. Please for help.
Regards

Comment: Can you show me you delegate implementations? Also, storyboard or nib, or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numberOfItemsInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/numberOfItemsInSection%3a) and [`numberOfSections`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/numberOfItemsInSection%3a)

Check each section, and see if this method returns 0. For example:

```
// Assume empty
BOOL isEmpty = YES;

for (int i = 0; i < collectionView.numberOfSections; i++) {
   // Check all sections, if one contains any items, set to NO and break out of loop, we don't need to check anymore
   if ([collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:i] != 0) {
      isEmpty = NO;
      break;
   }
}
```

Or, more obviously, directly access whatever is powering your `UICollectionView` (the datasource itself) and see if that is empty. I assume you are using an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, so check the counts of them, this is a much quicker solution, but it depends on the structure of your app.

Comment: Agreed. Some kind of data structure(i.e NSArray ...) should be maintaining the items being displayed so access the count via myDataStruct.count

Comment: Hi thanks for help:) It works correctly in my app. Have a nice day